Case expression with multiple rows in select statement
Below are the sample tables for your reference.
TableA



Col_A
Col_B




AAA
Active


BBB
InActive



TableB



Col_A
Col_C
Col_D




AAA
D_Fault
1


AAA
C_Fault
1


AAA
CH_Fault
0


BBB
D_Fault
1


BBB
C_Fault
0



The common column between table A and B is Col_A.
I need the below output.



Col_A
Col_B
D_Fault_Status
C_Fault_Status
CH_Fault_Status




AAA
Active
Faulty
Faulty
Not Faulty


BBB
InActive
Faulty
Not Faulty
Not Faulty



The logic is that, when Col_D is 1 has any specific value in Col_C then the Status must be Faulty for the respective Col_A. If Col_C is 0 or there is no record for the respective Fault, it can be Not Faulty. But the result must be in the same row for each Col_A which is unique.
I tried using select along with case expression, but it gives multiple rows as output, when tried with MAX(Case....), it looks for the max from the rows instead of all the row values.
I tried something like this, but it didn't help:
SELECT TableA.Col_A,
       Col_B,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Col_D = '1'
                 AND Col_C IN (D_Fault, E_Fault) THEN 'Faulty'
               WHEN Col_D = '0' THEN 'Not Faulty'
           END) AS D_Fault_Status,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Col_D = '1'
                 AND Col_C IN (C_Fault, EH_Fault) THEN 'Faulty'
               WHEN Col_D = '0' THEN 'Not Faulty'
           END) AS C_Fault_Status,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Col_D = '1'
                 AND Col_C IN (CH_Fault, CHE_Fault) THEN 'Faulty'
               WHEN Col_D = '0' THEN 'Not Faulty'
           END) AS CH_Fault_Status
FROM TableA
    JOIN TableB ON TableA.Col_A = TableB.Col_A;


You should post the MAX(CASE...) query, because that's the way to go here. Probably you aren't grouping correctly, but hard to say

Using Max, only fetches the MAX from the column and not verifying all the rows in the column. It's not working as expected.

Ok, just post the query you have and we'll see?

The best is to edit the question and put it there

I tried something like this, but it didn't help..
Select
TableA.Col_A,
Col_B,
MAX(
Case When Col_D = '1'
and Col_C in (D_Fault, E_Fault) then 'Faulty' When Col_D = '0' then 'Not Faulty' end
) as D_Fault_Status,
MAX(
Case when Col_D = '1'
and Col_C in (C_Fault, EH_Fault) then 'Faulty' when Col_D = '0' then 'Not Faulty' end
) as C_Fault_Status,
MAX(
Case when Col_D = '1'
and Col_C in (CH_Fault, CHE_Fault) then 'Faulty' when Col_D = '0' then 'Not Faulty' end
) as CH_Fault_Status
from
TableA
join TableB on TableA.Col_A = TableB.Col_A

is there always these 3 fault statuses? ( C, D  and CH) ?

not always, it may or may not present for Col_A value. If not present, we need to populate it as "Not Faulty"

This looks strikingly similar to your last question; now your just pivoting on a value rather than a row number... You already have 90% of the answer, so what about changing your solution to the last question didn't work here? What are your attempts? Why didn't they work?

In future please edit your query attenmpt into your question - it's very hard to view it in a comment.

If it's always these 3 statuses, it would be easier to do this:
select 
    a.COL_A
    , a.COL_B
    , case when max(case when Col_C = 'D_Fault' then Col_D end) = 1 then 'Faulty' else 'Not Faulty' end as D_Fault_Status
    , case when max(case when Col_C = 'C_Fault' then Col_D end) = 1 then 'Faulty' else 'Not Faulty' end as C_Fault_Status
    , case when max(case when Col_C = 'CH_Fault' then Col_D end) = 1 then 'Faulty' else 'Not Faulty' end as CH_Fault_Status
from TableA a
left join TableB b on a.COL_A = b.COL_A
group by a.COL_A, a.COL_B

Output:



COL_A
COL_B
D_Fault_Status
C_Fault_Status
CH_Fault_Status




AAA
Active
Faulty
Faulty
Not Faulty


BBB
InActive
Faulty
Not Faulty
Not Faulty


CCC
InActive
Not Faulty
Not Faulty
Not Faulty



fiddle
Be aware if Col_C includes any other values than those 3 above, they won't be considered by this query.
